# Keeping tab order in HTML with disabled elements using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Please take a look at this quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/wassimmansour/9v8nbqww/. Type something in the input "Optional Data" then press the tab key.

```
var ViewModel = function (opt, dep, oth) {
    this.optionalData = ko.observable(opt);
    this.dependantData = ko.observable(dep);
    this.otherData = ko.observable(oth);

    this.optionalDataPresent = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return this.optionalData().trim() !== '';
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("", "", "123"));
```

I need to be able to tab through and skip the "Dependent Data" input field when "Optional Data" is empty. But if "Optional Data" is not empty, the tab order must jump to "Dependent Data" before resuming to the rest of the inputs.

What is happening now is that the "Dependent Data" get's only enabled after the tab has skipped over it, which is not the intended or intuitive flow.

Any solution for this problem?

---

### Edit

The "optional data" field actually has to be formatted as "1,234.56" or "1,234.00". The code I am using for that is:

```
<input data-bind="masked: optionalData, mask: 'N2'" />

ko.bindingHandlers.masked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var mask = allBindingsAccessor().mask || 'N2';
        var val = $(element).val();
        if (val || val == 0) {
            val = parseFloat((val + '').replace(/,/g, ''));
            if (!isNaN(val)) $(element).val(val.format(mask));
            else $(element).val('');
        }

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var mask = allBindingsAccessor().mask || 'N2';
        var val = value;
        if (val || val == 0) {
            val = parseFloat((val + '').replace(/,/g, ''));
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                $(element).val(val.format(mask));
                return;
            }
        }
        $(element).val(value);
    }
};
```

I updated the code on http://jsfiddle.net/wassimmansour/9v8nbqww/7/ but it doesn't seem to run properly there.

I tested the 'valueUpdate' solution but it seems to be in conflict with the 'update' function used for formatting. Once a key is pressed, the input's value is updated and the formatting function is applied, which means formatting will be applied after each key press. This makes data entry impossible (if you type '1', the input is immediately updated to '1.00', then you have to move the cursor manually back to after 1 then press 2, then too the input will be formatted and will show '12.00').

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9v8nbqww/2/). I suggest using `valueUpdate: "keyup"` on the first field.

```html
<div class='liveExample'>Optional Data
    <br/>
    <input data-bind='value: optionalData, valueUpdate: "keyup"' />
    <br/>Dependent Data
    <br/>
    <input data-bind='value: dependantData, attr {disabled: !optionalDataPresent()}' />
    <br />Other Data
    <br/>
    <input data-bind='value: otherData' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. You solution works but I have another complication. I will add more details to the question.